# Is odometry required for navigation?

Tags: localization, navigation, odometry, gps, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to recreate a much more basic navigation stack.

I know navigation stack uses odometry (I am guessing for dead-reckoning and planning due to varying velocities). But let's assume I have a way of localising myself within the map with a GPS signal (2cm accuracy). Let's also assume that the vehicle is moving at a constant velocity. Would I still need odometry and /odom transforms for something like navigation stack to work? If so, why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314974/is-odometry-required-for-navigation?/) by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2019-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That would be "odometry" in the sense you need it. Odometry just refers to some high rate knowledge of your current state from your starting position (usually). This can include wheel encodes, IMUs, visual maps, etc but none of them are strictly required.

The information you would be getting falls into the category of odometry, so you should be good to go!

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-02-08**:
Thank you, I am surprised this is not explicitly mentioned anywhere!